# What is the difference between "Skip" and "I'm done"?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that, if I upvote a comment in the *First Posts* queue and then press *Skip* that my vote still remains.

I thought if I press *Skip* my changings or votes getting removed again.

Is that only for the comment votes, or for all changings and votes the case?

If that is for all changings, what is then the difference between *Skip* and *I'm done*? Just that the latter increases the count of the daily limit?

So it is possible to edit more posts (than 20/40) if I just press *Skip* instead of *I'm done*?

And why is there a limit of 20/40 every day if you can circumvent it that easy?
Only that it needs more time to get the badge?

Comment: @skrrgwasme no, my question is about "skip" and "I'm done" and not "Leave Closed” and “Skip” like in your link.

Comment: Oops. My bad. I've removed the comment.

Comment: I always figured _I'm Done_ is for when you literally can't take anymore. Flip a table and press _I'm Done_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I  thought if I press Skip my changings or votes getting removed again.

As you have found out, this is not the case.

In the First Posts queue, you can take multiple actions before you are done. This is why there is a separate <kbd>I'm done</kbd> button, which only becomes enabled after you have taken *at least one* action. You don't want to move to the next review until you've done all that you believe to be necessary.

If you take actions and then <kbd>Skip</kbd>, your actions will remain; but they will not be added to your review count. You'd effectively be doing more reviews, but they don't count towards your daily reviews or your badges.

As Ilmari Karonen points out in their [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341465/what-is-the-difference-between-skip-and-im-done/341466?noredirect=1#comment432824_341466), when you choose <kbd>Skip</kbd> the item will remain in the queue, for others to review. You may have taken actions, but they simply don't count as a review. If you choose <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>, it counts as having been handled by a reviewer. (Note that most queues require that each item is judged by multiple reviewers; so if it required to be reviewed by 3 people and you were the first, it would still need 2 more people to review it).

Note that there is not actually a limit of 20/40 edits; there is a limit of 20/40 *reviews*, per queue. These limits were imposed because some people mindlessly clicked their way through the queues to get that badge, causing harm to the site. Review is quality control and must be done with care.

You have found out that you could *effectively* do more reviewing by using <kbd>Skip</kbd> instead of <kbd>I'm Done</kbd>, but these will not be counted towards the badge.

Also, in practice, there are other limits. You have a limited number of votes and flags per day. You can also have at most 5 pending edits at the same time. So, even if you <kbd>Skip</kbd> everything, you would still be limited in how many actions you took every day.

Comment: I thought maybe its only for comment votes for some reason, or something like that.

Comment: @theoretisch No, it's simply that you can take multiple actions. There are other queues, like Suggested Edits, which don't offer "I'm Done" because there is only one action to take. BTW you can undo comment upvotes, but only once.

Comment: Ok,thank you. But why is there than the limit of 20/40 edits? (see my edited question)

Comment: @theoretisch I've updated the answer; hopefully this answers it?

Comment: I always assumed the *main* difference was that "Skip" would leave the post in the queue for someone else to (also) review, whereas "I'm Done" would remove it from the queue. Is that not correct?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen "Skip" tells the system that you haven't reviewed it, potentially leaving it for somebody else. "I'm Done" tells the system that you have reviewed it, potentially removing it from the queue. However, neither of these things are definite; for some queues multiple people can review a single item, and sometimes an old item is automatically removed from the queue anyway. **Use these buttons for their meaning, not for their effect.**

Comment: @IlmariKaronen True, "Skip" will leave it in the queue, "I'm Done" potentiall removes it. Updated the answer. Thanks for your input!